# Lubuntu 14.04 screen switching off

Tags: lubuntu

I recently installed Lubuntu 14.04 on my ASUS EeePC 1015PEM and set up everything i needed and its working just the way i want except for one thing my screen keeps switching after about 20 mins or so, here is what i've done and the problem still presists:

1. Set monitor options in power preferences to never sleep/switch off for both battery and ac
2. In Light Screen Locker settings i have bother Blank and Sleep set to never.

This wouldnt be a huge issue for me but i watch alot of tv shows and anime and its sucks having the screen switch off in the middle of an episode.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried playing with `xset`?

`xset -q` will show you your settings. There are many settings here that can be played with. Take a look at DPMS.

Try:

`xset s off` turns the screensaver off

`xset -dpms` turns off DPMS

Answer (score 1):

### Disable screen lock & screen switch off. Lubuntu 14.04.

I edited the file `~/.xsessionrc` using Nano or Gedit. (If there is no such file you just create new one).

```sh
nano ~/.xsessionrc
```

and add the following lines:

```sh
xset s off  # turns off default screensaver
xset -dpms  # turns off default standby, hibernate
```

Save it and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unchecking the "Monitor Power Management Control" checkbox in the Xfce Power Manager? I used to have that problem and I unchecked that and all of a sudden it stopped happening.

Also if you ever happen to need the screen to go blank after a certain time, use the Light Locker Settings instead of the Power Manager to set it. That's what I am using right now and the blanks don't happen anymore, or rather, the screen goes blank after the time I set it but just moving the mouse makes it come back now.

Answer (score 0):

How to change screen timeout on LUbuntu?

> LUbuntu search menu → Search screensaver → Display mode → Mode → Blank screen only → Select blank after the time you want to set for time out → Goto Advanced tab → Fill CheckBox "Quick power turn off in blank mode only"

Setting the last thing will turn power off your screen. But if you don't do that, then you will see only blank mode and not power off on screen.